# SQL query to select * from table, but return ID column as looked-up usernames

Tags: sql, lookup, bugzilla

I'm using Bugzilla, and I essentially want to SELECT * FROM bugs table in the "bugs" database. However, the "assigned_to" column actually contains integer values (IDs) instead of a string with the user name.

These IDs match primary keys in the "profiles" table (the "userid" column), and the string I want my query to return is actually stored in the "realname" column in that table.

How can I modify this query to capture all columns in "bugs," but perform a lookup on the assigned_to column and return usernames?

Comment: have you ever hear about joins in sql

Comment: @rahularyansharma have you ever heard of rhetorical questions?

Comment: @dbf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT b.*, p.realname FROM bugs b
JOIN profiles p
ON b.assigned_to = p.userid
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to modify this further so that the bugs.assigned_to column contains the strings (instead of having to parse a different column)?

Comment: Yes. You have to select all the columns from bugs except for assigned_to, then alias the column from profile as assigned_to (b.column1, b.column2..., p.realname assigned_to)